# How to read a Date from a DataTable into a textbox

Tags: asp.net, datatable

I have a date in a DataTable (dt).  How to read a Date from a DataTable into a textbox

I can read a string in fine:

```
    tbEvent.Text = dt.Rows[0].Field<String>(0);
```

I tried this but I get an error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime' to type
>   'System.String'.

```
        tbDate.Text = dt.Rows[0].Field<DateTime>(1);
```

Regards
Tea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
 tbDate.Text = dt.Rows[0].Field<DateTime>(1).ToString();
```

`Textbox.Text` only accepts string values - so you need to convert.

**Updated**

To format the string to show specific values you can use the custom format strings - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

so the above becomes

```
 tbDate.Text = dt.Rows[0].Field<DateTime>(1).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

for db date `12/23/2012 12:25:45` it will produce `23/12/2012`.

Comment: Worked thanks.  How can I trim the data that it shows just date instead of date and time?  Can I do it in the same statement?

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling to add my dates correctly on my textbox but finally figured it out

Convert.ToDateTime(dataRow[3].ToString()).ToString("MM/yyyy/dd").ToString();

I changed the format to ("MM/yyyy/dd") instead of ("yyyy/MM/dd")